# set total number of checkbox in array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have check box array like this

```
  for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++)      
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkLimit[]" id="chkLimit_<?php echo $j;?>" value="<?php echo $j;?>" />
```

i got 10 check box

and i write the jquery code like this...

```
  $(document).ready(
    function (){
    setLimitSelection();
    }


);


   function setLimitSelection(){
    $('input[name="chkLimit[]"]').limitSelection(
        {
            // number of items to limit to
            limit: 4,
            // on error, do this
            onfailure: function (n){
                $("#idCheckboxMsg").html(
                    "You can not select more than " + n + " items."
                );
                return false;
            },
            // on success, do this
            onsuccess: function (n){
                $("#idCheckboxMsg").html("");
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
    $('select[name="selLimit[]"]').limitSelection(10);
}

$("input.chkLimit").click(function() {
    var numSelected = $("input.chkLimit[]:checked").length;
    var numLeft = 10 - parseInt(numSelected);
    $("#statusBox").html("You have "+numSelected+" CD's selected.<br>You have "+numLeft+" selections left.");
});
```

what i want is: user can't select more than 4 check boxs

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should get the job done for you:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']").change(
        var checked = $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox'][checked]").length;
        if(checked == 4){
            $("#myCheckboxes input[@type='checkbox']").not(":checked").attr('disabled',true);
        }else{
            $("#myCheckboxes input[@type='checkbox']").not(":checked").attr('disabled',false);
        }
    )
});
```

Every time the checked state of a checkbox changes, it looks at how many checkboxes are checked.  If there are 4, it disables the unchecked boxes, otherwise it enables them.  This assumes that they all live in a container called `#myCheckboxes`

Comment: you're going to have to give me a little more information than that if you'd like me to continue to help.  Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @inkedmn had some syntax errors but the comment box just isn't adequate to elaborate. So, here's what I think he's trying to do:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        var checked = $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
        if(checked == 4){
            $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']")
                .attr('disabled',true)
                .filter(':not(:checked)')
                .attr('disabled',false);
        } else {
            $("#myCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']").attr('disabled',false);
        }
    )
});
```

That should get it done for you.

Comment: Oops, I had a typo. Try the new version.